# Attach Eclipse php debugger to Apache server

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I have built an app that sends requests to a server.

I also built a server to response those requests.  I have a PHP server locally (LAMP).

Now, for debug purposes , I want to debug the requests that my app is sending to the server. But I don't want to do that separately (printing the app's request and than start debug the server with that request),

I want eclipse (PDT installed and xdebug) to stop at the first line of the PHP script running by the server WHEN the app is sending a request to the server.

How can I do that ?